# Django - correctly redirecting based on category

Tags: django, redirect

I'm having two issues:

EDIT:

I made some tweaks and partially resolved the issue. But now, when I submit a new blog post form it takes me to the wrong url and no matter what url I try, I can't find the full post. When I click on a link to the full post I get a Type Error "Object "Post" is not iterable". Category "progresstracker" works perfectly, "blogtopics/.." doesn't.

Here's the latest code:

## views.py

```
def pt_detail(request, slug, category):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug, category__slug=category)

    template = CATEGORY_TEMPLATES.get(post.category.slug)
    return render(request, template, {'post': post})


def bt_detail(request, slug, category):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug, category__slug=category)
    template = CATEGORY_TEMPLATES.get(post.category.slug)
    return render(request, template, {'post': post})

def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            if post.category.slug == 'blog-topics':
                return redirect('bt_detail', slug=post.slug, category=post.category)
            else:
                return redirect('pt_detail', slug=post.slug, category=post.category)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

def post_edit(request, slug, category):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug, category__slug=category)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            if post.category.slug == 'blog-topics':
                return redirect('bt_detail', slug=post.slug, category=post.category)
            else:
                return redirect('pt_detail', slug=post.slug, category=post.category)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^home/$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^blogtopics/computer-science/$', views.compsci, name='computer-science'),
    url(r'^blogtopics/data-science/$', views.datasci, name='data-science'),
    url(r'^blogtopics/other/$', views.other, name='other'),
    url(r'^blogtopics/$', views.blogtopics, name='blogtopics'),
    url(r'^resources/$', views.resources, name='resources'),
    url(r'^new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    url(r'^progresstracker/$', views.progresstracker, name='progresstracker'),
    url(r'^blogtopics/(?P<category>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.bt_detail, name='bt_detail'),
    url(r'^blogtopics/(?P<category>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
    url(r'^(?P<category>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.pt_detail, name='pt_detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<category>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
]
```

## computerscience.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block nav %}
    <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/progresstracker">Progress Tracker</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="active" href="/blogtopics" class="dropbtn">Blog Topics</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="/blogtopics/computer-science">Computer Science</a>
            <a href="/blogtopics/data-science">Data Science</a>
            <a href="/blogtopics/other">Other</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/resources">Resources</a></li>
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
  <div id="content">
                <div class="padding">
                <p style="padding-top: 50px"> 
                <div class="post_list">
            {% for post in post %}  
                <h3><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url_bt }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
                <p>{{ post.published_date }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
{% endblock %}
```

## models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    posted = models.DateField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('books.Category', related_name='%(class)s_slug')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default = timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/%s/%s/" % (self.category, self.slug)

    def get_absolute_url_bt(self):
        return "/blogtopics/%s/%s/" % (self.category, self.slug)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a couple things going on here. First you said that any category will get sent to a blank computerscience page. This tells me that your `if` statement is always resulting in false so it's trying to render the `computerscience.html` template. The `pt_detail` view has a single Post object(`ptpost`) in the context. The `compsci` view uses the same `computerscience.html` template to render a QuerySet of Post objects using `posts` in the context. You can't do both. Since your template is expecting `posts` in your context and only finds `ptpost` it can't render anything, hence the blank page.

As far as using category to determine which template to use, you could use a series of `elif` statements, or you could do something like this:

```
CATEGORY_TEMPLATES = {
    'progresstracker': 'blog/pt_detail.html',
    'anothercategory': 'blog/ac_detail.html',
    'yetanothercategory': 'blog/yac_detail.html',
}

def pt_detail(request, slug, category):
    ptpost = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug, category__slug=category)
    template = CATEGORY_TEMPLATES.get(ptpost.category.slug, 'blog/default_detail.html')
    return render(request, template, {'ptpost': ptpost})
```

This will select the category from the `CATEGORY_TEMPLATES` dictionary and use `blog/default_detail.html` as the default if the current category isn't in the dict.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I made some tweaks (see original post edit) and half fixed the issue but am still struggling. Appreciate any help.